# how to package a native library into a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar

I have two projects: a standard java application (project A), and Java dynamic web application (project B).

Project A itself makes calls to native libraries. I included this library in project A's build directory and everything runs fine as standalone (without involving project B).

For Project B, I successfully hosted the application on Tomcat Server from within Eclipse; It works correctly when I don't involve project A.

Problem is when I in actually add code to project B to call project A, I get an error whenever project A tries to load its native library to compute some function that is implemented in in the native library. I get that the native library cannot be found. Where is the right place to put this library?

Things I have tried:

- Exported project A as a runnable jar (while making sure to include
  its native  library).
- Added the native library from project A,    directly into the
  WEB-INF/lib of Tomcat's directory for the host    server (project B).
- Added the the native library from project A    directly to the build
  path of project B.

And none of these seem to work. I have seen some similar problem on SO, as I have summarized above. I'm I still missing something?

Apologies for this one being long. It seems to be an eclipse config issue, and not code related. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: @ArkaGhosh no, I am using neither maven nor ant -- Just the standard eclipse built-in build tool.

Comment: Check this [link](http://codyburleson.com/2013/05/21/automatically-build-and-include-one-eclipse-project-into-another/) if it is of any help.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh I wonder if that method in the link you provided will also include native libraries that are referenced by the "libraries project".

Comment: Try referring `ProjectA` in the 'Project References' tab.

Comment: didnt work with that.